# How to merge excel columns into multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge

I have two sheets in Excel with the following content:

***Sheet1***

```
Product    Quantity

Product1   10
Product2   15
Product3   20
```

***Sheet2***

```
Product    Price

Product1   120
Product2   235
Product3   350
```

Now, I want to merge these two sheets into Sheet3 as the following:

***Sheet3***

```
Product    Parameter   Value

Product1   Quantity    10
Product1   Price       120
Product2   Quantity    15
Product2   Price       235
Product3   Quantity    20
Product3   Price       350
```

These numbers are just examples here. The real data is too big, with nearly 2000 rows. So I cannot copy and paste them manually. Besides, the data are dynamically changed from the web, so I need some formula to re-arrange them automatically every time.

Which functions or formulas can I use to re-arrange these data as above ?

Answer (score -1):

Just copy one below the other and Sort the first column.

If you require something more automated, use `Power Query` (aka `Data --> Get & Transform` in Excel 2016) to do that by creating a Query that uses the two tables for the Source.

When you add to either table, just `Refresh` the `Query`.

Comment: It would be useful if the downvoter added a comment as to the reason for the down vote.